# Issue with Folder.Files when some files are missing a last modified date

Tags: powerbi

`Folder.Files("some path")` aborts and returns the error

> Expression.Error: Not a valid Win32 FileTime. Parameter name: fileTime

once it encounters a file missing a last modified timestamp. How might I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual folder name, you can use the `GET DATA` window to import the data. Once the data is imported, you can go to the "EDIT QUERY" window and check out the query being used. If you are still facing issues, we may need further details to figure this out.